# Error in Puppet agent execution while ierating in a template

Tags: loops, templates, hash, puppet

Here an extract of the parameter section of my manifest:

```
  Array $secretsproperties_diffusion_siteweb_ftp_keys = ['eliasseAN','eliasseAN.server2'],

  Hash $eloi_eliasse = {'eliasseAN' => ['ftpeliasse','Eliasse0000'], 'eliasseAN.server2' => ['ftpeliasse','Eliasse0000']},
```

Here an extract of the manifest itself:

```
  file { "generate-secrets-properties-file":
    ensure  => 'file',
    path    => "${app_working_directory}/cfg/secrets.properties",
    owner   => "${appuser[0]}",
    group   => "${appuser[0]}",
    content => template("${name}/secrets.properties.erb"),
    notify => "secretsproperties_diffusion_siteweb_ftp_keys : $content1",
    notify => "eloi_eliasse : $content2",

    require => [
      User["${appuser[0]}"],
      File['create-dir-cfg']
    ]
  }
```

and to finish, an extract of the template, called `secrets.properties.erb`:

```
<%- @secretsproperties_diffusion_siteweb_ftp_keys.each do |key| -%>
<%= key %>.ftp.login=<%= @eloi_eliasse[key][0] %> # That's line 7
<%= key %>.ftp.pwd=<%= @eloi_eliasse[key][1] %>
<% end -%>
```

When launching the Puppet agent, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Failed to parse template appeloi/secrets.properties.erb:
  Filepath: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/modules/appeloi/templates/secrets.properties.erb
  Line: 7
  Detail: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/modules/appeloi/manifests/init.pp, line: 322, column: 16) on node eloi-pre-tst-mgt.assemblee-nationale.fr
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Debug: HTTP POST https://frm-dev-app.assemblee-nationale.fr:8140/puppet/v3/catalog/eloi-pre-tst-mgt.assemblee-nationale.fr returned 500 Server Error
```

There is obviously someting I'm missing, but I can't find what.

**Edit:** Here some context elements. This puppet script get parameters injection from a Foreman server and the Puppet agent is launched by a script through a Gitlab runner (which also passes some data using Facter). But neither `$secretsproperties_diffusion_siteweb_ftp_keys` nor `$eloi_eliasse` are currently overriden by data from any other source, as I'm trying to get that part of the code to work before plugin it to any external system. I had a very similar code in the previous version, which worked, and I can't see any difference. Except that the current version is not working, of course.

Comment: The error implies a nonexistent key is being specified for accessing the value within `eloi_eliasse`, and this could be occurring for a variety of reasons outside of the question content. This could be greatly simplified and the error also possibly fixed by iterating through `eloi_eliasse` instead of a secondary array.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard I put all the code which seemed involved in the issue in my question. If you think something is missing, don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Comment: *Manifests* do not have "parameter sections".  Class definitions do, so perhaps that's what you mean.  But the default parameter values specified there can be overridden by automatic data binding or by values explicitly bound to those parameters by a resource-like class declaration.  It is unclear from the information given what variable values the template is actually receiving.

Comment: Also, consider this: do you really need `$secretsproperties_diffusion_siteweb_ftp_keys` at all?  Would it be sufficient to instead iterate all the mappings in `$eloi_eliasse`?

Comment: I recommend designating your data types more specifically to ensure that the data actually provided have the correct form (it looks like `Array[String]` and `Hash[String, Array[String, 2, 2]]` are what your code requires).  If you stick with `$secretsproperties_diffusion_siteweb_ftp_keys` then I would also recommend either validating on the Puppet side that all the elements are in fact keys of `$eloi_eliasse`, or else dealing appropriately on the template side with elements that are not, in fact, such keys.